# how to preload next and previous view in UipageViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

As after a lot of search and RND and after many different code implementation the issue of delay in swipe was not resolved so i guess preload the next and previous view controllers will resolve my issue of swipe delay.

how to load next and previous view before swipe. Didnot find the solution after long rnd and search

Comment: Refer this one :- https://github.com/UnicornTV/Swift-Example-UIPageViewController

Comment: thanks i am implementing and check it...

Answer (score 3):

You can call nextController.loadViewIfNeeded() and prevController.loadViewIfNeeded(), after showing visible controller!

```
pageViewController?.setViewControllers([controller], direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: { (_) in
    if let nextController = /*Find it*/ {
       nextController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
    if let prevController = /*Find it*/ {
       prevController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
})
```

You must find nextController and prevController in the code, I think that is easy.

Comment: this solved me a loading problem but didnt made the scroll totally smooth

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` to monitor the events of  `UIPageViewController`, when it `didFinishAnimating` you can load the previous and next view.