# How to preload next page when UIPageViewController initialize

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

There are many SO questions talk about preload but seems none of them discuss how to do this during initialize.

I want to preload the next page when `UIPageViewController` is initialized.
For example, I initial `UIPageViewController` with the following code.

```
// [firstVC, secondVC]
setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true)
```

Unfortunately, datasource delegate function won't be called at the moment.
They will be called when user interaction involve.
In another word, when user swipe page.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

I tried to "scroll" view programmatically.
It shows blank, there is nothing on the scrollView at the region.

```
// self is a UIPageViewController
if let scrollView = self.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView {
    var offset = scrollView.contentOffset
    offset.x += 200
    scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
}
```

Also tried to set 2 viewControllers when initialize but app crash.

```
setViewControllers([firstVC, secondVC], direction: .forward, animated: true)
```

Can I preload without user interaction?

---

Update.
So when user open the pageVC, I want to do a small swipe to user to demo this new feature, like the left image, since user doesn't know they can swipe so no user interaction at the moment.

If I can't preload the next view, it will look like the right image (white means nothing in this sample), empty view will make user confused, they could think this is a bug.
[image]

Update:
[Github](https://github.com/xxi511/PageViewTest)

Comment: Documentation clearly states: When defining a page view controller interface, you can provide the content view controllers one at a time

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Comment: If you need to preload some data inside those view controllers you can do that without involving UIPageViewController.

Comment: I am not only want to preload data, I want to preload the next view, sometimes I want to do a swipe action to user

Comment: Could you please provide example gif showing desired behavior and the resulting one?

Comment: Please check update, hope this is clear :)

Comment: Did you try this solution? :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166390/17834877

Comment: doesn't work, the view doesn't shows in the scrollView

Comment: I will research myself when I get to the computer

Comment: How do you setup layout in your view controllers?

Comment: Please share your code which setups layout of UIPageViewControllers child UIViewControllers

Comment: I suppose the problem maybe what you layout subviews later than in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Many "built-in" components and controls are difficult to customize, and can produce unpredictable results when trying to use them in a non-default manner. `UIPageViewController` may not be the best way to go for your desired behavior. How many "pages" do you have? A few? 20? 50? Are they "heavy" - as in, lots of content, images, etc? Are they interactive or static?

Comment: @BulatYakupov update repo link, please check, it is super basic nothing special

Comment: @DonMag it depends, one to thousands are possible.  I though content is not the problem here? That is independent VC, nothing much to UIPageViewController ?

Comment: @xxi - the problem is that setting the `.contentOffset` on the page controller's scroll view does not trigger a call to either `viewControllerBefore` or `viewControllerAfter` ... it appears those are only called after `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`. So nothing is telling the controller to "load and position" the next view. Since you are using `Scroll` rather than `PageCurl`, it's very possible that you will be better off using a `UICollectionView`.