# Managing UIPageViewController with ScrollView is not loading Next/Previous contents

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer, uipagecontrol

I have a 3 view controllers in my UIPageViewController. I am accesing the UIPageViewController's  scroll view from one of my view controller which is in UIPageViewController and managing it with a UIPanGesture. I am always in mid controller and The problem is the content is in next or previous never gets shown if I don't swipe via UIPageViewController. I see the background of the UIPageViewController. Logic works, everything in main thread but for somehow i need to say UIPageViewController hey prepare the next data i am coming with UIPanGesture. I noticed When i swipe a little bit in my UIPageViewController it's firing the viewController after and viewcontroller before methods. Here is the code

The code I am sending how much it should scroll the UIPageViewController from my Controller :

```
    @objc func panRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            
            switch overflowState {
            case .on(let lastRecordedGestureTranslation):
                if gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .possible {
                    self.viewModel.chatScrollDetectedSwipeDirection = nil
                    self.viewModel.objectToMove = nil
                    self.viewModel.chatScrollViewPosition = self.checkTableViewPosition(chatTableView)
                    self.viewModel.baseToControllerDelegate?.onOverflowEnded()
                    overflowState = .off
                    chatTableScrollView?.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
                    self.viewModel.baseToControllerDelegate?.pageControllerSetContentOffsets(prog: 0)
                    return
                }
                

//This is where i am calling hey page controller start moving
                let fullTranslationY = gesture.translation(in: view).y
                let delta = fullTranslationY - lastRecordedGestureTranslation
                overflowState = .on(lastRecordedGestureTranslation: fullTranslationY)
                
                self.viewModel.baseToControllerDelegate?.onOverflow(delta: delta)
```

```
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true // so that both the pan gestures on scrollview will be triggered
    }
```

The code to move UIPageViewController from one my page

```
    func onOverflow(delta: CGFloat) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            guard let scrollViewA = self.pageViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView else { return }
            scrollViewA.contentOffset.y -= delta / 2
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

**Things I tried : **
Manually firing viewControllerBefore and viewControllerAfter (Did not work)
** Things i did not understand : **:
If i move in my controllers view setViewController animated true and false. It works but creates a glitch view that my controllers are swiping 2 times untill i reach my mid controller.

Comment: `UIPageViewController` does a lot of "behind the scenes" work. What are you really trying to accomplish? It's very possible that `UIPageViewController` is not the correct approach.

Comment: I am trying to move my UIPageViewController if my table view is already at bottom. This is just the thing i want to do. Everything works i put all my logic well rather than my next page i see the background of my UIPageviewController  if i move it with delegate. But if i move it with somewhere else rather than table view only for a time i can see the next page with table view too

Comment: So... your post states: *"always in mid controller"* ... do you mean you have 3 pages, the "mid" page has a table view, and when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the table view and then drags up ... you want to transition to the next page?

Comment: You can think of like a tiktok like scrolling page yes i am always at mid and you can think the table view is chat. When chat is at bottom I am changing the scroll view of my page controller. It should show the next page the last page at the background but it shows nothing just the background color my of UIPageViewController. I am always in mid means i am loading the pre and next content the reason i am always in mid is this is infinite scroll UIPageViewController. The directly transition to next will not give a control like user dragging the page.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what a *"tiktok like scrolling page"* means. Can you describe - in plain language - what you mean? What is your view hierarchy? Is the table view embedded in a "page"? Or, do you have a `UIPageViewController` and a *separate* table view? So as you scroll the table view you want to (partially) scroll the page view?

Comment: 1- I have a UIPageViewController that is edge to edge of the screen ( full screen )
2- This page controller contains 3 pages 0 - 1 - 2 and I am initally start at page 1 (the middle one)
3- My all view controllers inside the Page controller are same but that is not the case.
4- My view controller has a table view. I added a UIPanGesture on it. That pan gesture checks the if table view is at bottom controls the table view is not swipes my UIPageViewController.
5- The bug appears is "IF I NEVER USED UIPAGECONTROLLER TO CHECK CONTENT ABOVE OR DOWN IT IS NOT SHOWING UP IF I MOVE MY PAGE WITHPAN

Comment: Happy to try and help, but still unsure of your UI ... is it either "A" or "B" in this image? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z90qz.png

Comment: It's B also to let you know more about the problem you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217412/how-to-preload-next-page-when-uipageviewcontroller-initialize this is the exact scenario happening. I don't want to use Collection because each of my page has lots of feature and it will be hard to deal with reusable cells. Changing pagecontroller to scroll could be an option. any other option or a trick that can let me preload the next with pageController?

Comment: So, is the issue that you want to drag / scroll the table view up, and when it reaches the last cell *continue dragging* to scroll to the next page, without the user having to lift the touch and start dragging again (and vice-versa for dragging down)? If so, does your Pan Gesture implementation accomplish that in a plain scroll view?